# Polymer <paper-scroll-header-panel> event 'content-scroll' does not show scrolling position

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

While using Polymer `<paper-scroll-header-panel>` the event `'content-scroll'` listener function does not show the scrolling position:

```
window.addEventListener('content-scroll', function (ev) {
    console.log('event: content-scroll ' + '\nwindow.scrollY = ' +   window.scrollY );
});
```

Full page code: https://jsbin.com/hofice/edit?html,console,output
The code is an example, link hrefs`<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">` are as per my app directory structure.

If `Polymer.IronScrollTargetBehavior` is applicable, please help how to implement it on page with `<paper-scroll-header-panel>`.

I know that window.scrollY is not working in old IE.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar with paper-header-panel. In paper-header-panel.html, it says the following in the comment:

```
    /**
     * Fired when the content has been scrolled.  `event.detail.target` returns
     * the scrollable element which you can use to access scroll info such as
     * `scrollTop`.
     *
     *     <paper-header-panel on-content-scroll="scrollHandler">
     *       ...
     *     </paper-header-panel>
     *
     *
     *     scrollHandler: function(event) {
     *       var scroller = event.detail.target;
     *       console.log(scroller.scrollTop);
     *     }
     *
     * @event content-scroll
     */
```

I just browsed the paper-scroll-header-panel.html and it should do somethings similar.